# Turn on collision unity 2d game

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I'm trying to make my 'monster' turn when it collides with a wall. The only problem with my script is that it only turns the 'monster' when it collides with my character or another 'monster'...
I tried adding rigidbodies to the walls,... But i can't figure it out it seems.

Here's my javascript script:

```
#pragma strict
var box : GameObject;

function OnCollisionEnter( hit : Collision)

{ 

box.transform.Rotate(0,180,0);

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You tried add colliders on the walls?

Comment: Yes i did on all the walls.

Comment: If you're using 2D physics be sure to use OnCollisionEnter**2D**

Comment: That doesn't work :/

Comment: Have you checked that all your colliders are either 3D colliders or 2D colliders and all of the gameobject are on same layer or on layers that are colliding with each other?

Comment: They are all 2D and are on layers that are colliding with each other :/

Comment: If OnCollisionEnter is working then it means you are not playing with 2D. Can you confirm that your wall and character both are in same mode, i.E either in 2D or 3D?

Comment: They all have 2D colliders and a 2D rigidbody

Answer (score 0):

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
    if (coll.gameObject.name == "NAME_OF_YOUR_MONSTER") {
        box.transform.Rotate(0,180,0);
    }
}
```

And add this script to your walls. That should work.

Comment: OH, i know what your problem is, because i'm having the same problem, the game just ignore the walls and i still don't know why. If i found out why, i right the answer

Comment: Okay, I hope you find something!